# Magento 1.9 add configurable product to cart via url

Tags: php, magento

I've been figure it out since ytd and still not found the answer yet. 
On my magento 1.9 i made a custom module that require adding product to cart via url. no problem with simple product, but in configurable product, product not save to cart. here are a couple of url i've used :

```
207 = configurable product ID
136 = super_attribute ID
14 = super_attribute value

http://storeurl.com/checkout/cart/add/product/207/?super_attribute[136]=14
http://storeurl.com/checkout/cart/add/product/207?super_attribute[136]=14
http://storeurl.com/checkout/cart/add/product/207?super_attribute[136]=14/form_key/cRnetTlCw43Jtr9B/
```

none of those url working. i feel like i'm stuck here. Please somebody help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In latest magento versions we need to add form key also.

```
https://{site-name}/checkout/cart/add/product/{product_id}/form_key/{form_key}?super_attribute[{attribute_id}]={attribute_value}&super_attribute[{attribute_id}]={attribute_value}
```